# Como calcular a distância entre dois pontos e calcular distância ABC, CAB, BAC? em C

Tags: c

criei em sala de aula esse programa que calcula a distância entre dois pontos e em seguida dá a opção de 3 caminhos diferentes: ABC, BAC ou CAB.

Gostaria de dicas para otimizar meu código, ideias de como melhorá-lo e também dicas de novas funcionalidades...

segue o código:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
        float ax, bx,cx, ay, by, cy;
        float AB, BC, AC;
        float distancia;
        int rota;

        printf("Digite o valor de Ax\n");
        scanf("%f", &ax);
        printf("Digite o valor de Ay\n");
        scanf("%f", &ay);
        printf("Digite o valor de Bx\n");
        scanf("%f", &bx);
        printf("Digite o valor de By\n");
        scanf("%f", &by);
        printf("Digite o valor de Cx\n");
        scanf("%f", &cx);
        printf("Digite o valor de Cy\n");
        scanf("%f", &cy);


        AB=sqrt(pow((bx-ax),2)+pow((by-ay),2));
        printf("A distancia entre os pontos A e B eh %f\n", AB);

        AC=sqrt(pow((cx-ax),2)+pow((cy-ay),2));
        printf("A distancia entre os pontos A e C eh %f\n", AC);
        BC=sqrt(pow((cx-bx),2)+pow((cy-by),2));
        printf("A distancia entre os pontos B e C eh %f\n\n", BC);
        printf("Escolha uma rota: ABC = 1, BAC = 2 ou CAB = 3\n");
        scanf("%d", &rota);
        switch (rota)
        {
          case 1:
            distancia = AB + BC;
            printf("A distancia entre os pontos ABC eh %f\n", distancia);
          break;

          case 2:
            distancia = AB + BC;
            printf("A distancia entre os pontos BAC eh %f\n", distancia);
          break;

          case 3:
            distancia = AB + BC;
            printf("A distancia entre os pontos CAB eh %f\n", distancia);
          break;

          default :
        printf("ROTA INVALIDA!!!");

        }

        system("pause"); 
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dica que eu dou, então, é sobre estilo.
Você já tem alguma noção de estrutura de dados? Seria interessante deixar este código mais limpo, usando `struct`s e encapsulando algumas ações repetidas em sub-rotinas.

Por exemplo, os pontos podem ser abstraídos dessa forma:

```
typedef struct point{
  float xcoord;
  float ycoord;
} point;

/* Uso: point A = set_point(4.0,3.0) */
point set_point(float xcoord, float ycoord){
  point ret;

  ret.xcoord = xcoord;
  ret.ycoord = ycoord;

  return ret;
}
```

Com isto, a distância entre dois pontos pode ser calculada por esta função:

```
float distance(point A, point B){
  float dx = A.xcoord - B.xcoord;
  float dy = A.ycoord - B.ycoord;

  return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```

Não recomendaria usar a função `pow`, dado que a multiplicação nativa é(?) mais rápida.

Outra coisa seria essa frase `"A distância entre os pontos ABC é"...`. Esse fraseado é confuso. Que tal `"O comprimento da rota A-B-C é"...`?

Eu também sugeriria algo mais verboso na parte da coleta dos valores das coordenadas dos pontos, algo como "digite a coordenada x do ponto A", "digite a coordenada y do ponto C".

Comment: +1 por sugerir quebrar o código em subrotinas e usar estruturas de dados. Eu só recomendaria usar `.x` e `.y`em vez de `.xcoord` e `.ycoord`, que é redundante, e passar os parâmetros pra `distance()` por referência, em vez de por valor.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, Anderson!